# Set UIView orientation according to iPhone orientation (Landscape,Portrait)

Tags: ios, objective-c, device-orientation

I am making a Camera App which records video both in landscape and portrait mode. I am using a uiview over that view controller. It is working fine in portrait mode. How to make that uiview set accordingly in landscape mode

Comment: Check this -: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959347/different-portrait-landscape-views-in-storyboard-and-swift

Comment: If you set auto-layout, I don't think you face any problem. Pls add Images in landscape and portraite both.

Comment: I am not able to recognize if the orientation is in landscape or Potrait ? please let knw is there any methods to recognize orientation

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width>[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height?@"Landscape":@"Portrait");`

Comment: It should be noted that OP is likely displaying the camera output into the layer w/ CALayer commands. Not `addSubview:`. This may cause further issues, it would be helpful/advised for OP to post their code.